# How can I place designated Fibonacci labels on the right side, and shorten the lines to not extend all the way to the right?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I have a code that auto generates specified Fibonacci levels based off buy/sell signals. I am trying to get the labels on the right side instead of left, and shorten the lines so that they don't extend all the way to the right, but by only so much and preferably have the start of the lines aligned with the buy/sell candle they are printed on. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this.

https://www.tradingview.com/x/ShCwlfBE/

```
var linezerovalue = 0.0

var line236value = 0.0

var line650value = 0.0

var line1000value = 0.0

var line11383value = 0.0

var line1618value = 0.0

var line2000value = 0.0

var linedifference = 0.0



var line line0 = na

var line line236 = na

var line line650 = na

var line line1000 = na

var line line11383 = na

var line line1618 = na

var line line2000 = na





//labels

var label label0 = na

var label label236 = na

var label label650 = na

var label label1000 = na

var label label11383 = na

var label label1618 = na

var label label2000 = na







linezerovalue := buySignal ? l10 : sellSignal ? h10 : na

line1000value := buySignal ? high : sellSignal ? low : na

linedifference := abs(linezerovalue - line1000value)

line236value := buySignal ? linezerovalue + (0.236*linedifference) : sellSignal ?  
linezerovalue - (0.236*linedifference) : na

line650value := buySignal ? linezerovalue + (0.650*linedifference) : sellSignal ?  
linezerovalue - (0.650*linedifference) : na

line11383value := buySignal ? line1000value + (0.382*linedifference) : sellSignal ?  
line1000value - (0.382*linedifference) : na

line1618value := buySignal ? line1000value + (1.0*linedifference) : sellSignal ?  
line1000value - (1.0*linedifference) : na

line2000value := buySignal ? line1000value + (1.618*linedifference) : sellSignal ?  
line1000value - (1.618*linedifference) : na





if buySignal or sellSignal

line.delete(line0)

line.delete(line236)

line.delete(line650)

line.delete(line1000)

line.delete(line11383)

line.delete(line1618)

line.delete(line2000)



label.delete(label0)

label.delete(label236)

label.delete(label650)

label.delete(label1000)

label.delete(label11383)

label.delete(label1618)

label.delete(label2000)



label0 := label.new(bar_index[1], linezerovalue, text = "(SL) - " + tostring(float(linezerovalue)), xloc = xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.price, color = color.white, style = label.style_none, textcolor = color.white, size = size.normal)

label236 := label.new(bar_index[1], line236value, text = "(RM) - " + tostring(float(line236value)), xloc = xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.price, color = color.white, style = label.style_none, textcolor = color.white, size = size.normal)

label650 := label.new(bar_index[1], line650value, text = "(Entry) - " + tostring(float(line650value)), xloc = xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.price, color = color.white, style = label.style_none, textcolor = color.white, size = size.normal)

label1000 := label.new(bar_index[1], line1000value, text = "(Break) - " + tostring(float(line1000value)), xloc = xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.price, color = color.white, style = label.style_none, textcolor = color.white, size = size.normal)

label11383 := label.new(bar_index[1], line11383value, text = "(TP 1) - " + tostring(float(line11383value)), xloc = xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.price, color = color.white, style = label.style_none, textcolor = color.white, size = size.normal)

label1618 := label.new(bar_index[1], line1618value, text = "(TP 2) - " + tostring(float(line1618value)), xloc = xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.price, color = color.white, style = label.style_none, textcolor = color.white, size = size.normal)

label2000 := label.new(bar_index[1], line2000value, text = "(TP 3) - " + tostring(float(line2000value)), xloc = xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.price, color = color.white, style = label.style_none, textcolor = color.white, size = size.normal)



line0 := line.new(x1 = bar_index[1],y1 = linezerovalue,x2 = bar_index,y2 = linezerovalue,xloc = xloc.bar_index, extend = extend.right, color = buySignal ? color.red : color.red)

line236 := line.new(x1 = bar_index[1],y1 = line236value,x2 = bar_index,y2 = line236value,xloc = xloc.bar_index, extend = extend.right, color = buySignal ? color.fuchsia : color.fuchsia)

line650 := line.new(x1 = bar_index[1],y1 = line650value,x2 = bar_index,y2 = line650value,xloc = xloc.bar_index, extend = extend.right, color = buySignal ? color.blue: color.blue)

line1000 := line.new(x1 = bar_index[1],y1 = line1000value,x2 = bar_index,y2 = line1000value,xloc = xloc.bar_index, extend = extend.right, color = buySignal ? color.lime : color.lime)

line11383 := line.new(x1 = bar_index[1],y1 = line11383value,x2 = bar_index,y2 = line11383value,xloc = xloc.bar_index, extend = extend.right, color = buySignal ? color.green : color.green)

line1618 := line.new(x1 = bar_index[1],y1 = line1618value,x2 = bar_index,y2 = line1618value,xloc = xloc.bar_index, extend = extend.right, color = buySignal ? color.green : color.green)

line2000 := line.new(x1 = bar_index[1],y1 = line2000value,x2 = bar_index,y2 = 
    line2000value,xloc = xloc.bar_index, extend = extend.right, color = buySignal ? 
color.green : color.green)
```

// plot(l10, style = plot.style_linebr)

Answer (score 0):

For your label `x` values and line `x2` values you can use `bar_index +` *integer* eg

`label.new(x = bar_index + 50, y = ......)`

and change the `extend` parameter for lines to `extend.none`

The label style also controls the origin point for the labels, so you might want to try using `label.style_label_lower_right`